# Announce everything in a UIWebView using VoiceOver?

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, accessibility, voiceover

My app is primarily loading text-based HTML files into a `UIWebView`. When a new HTML file is loaded, I'd like it to be read in its entirety to VoiceOver users. Right now, it reads only the headings within `<h1>` tags, and then stops.

It works great if I double finger swipe down. I'd really just like to automate that process upon each new page load. Right now I'm using the following within `webViewDidFinishLoad`:

```
UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityScreenChangedNotification, self.theText)
UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityAnnouncementNotification, self.theText)
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't do this! Let the user control their own interaction with the page. Trying to do this would be akin to forcing a sighted user to read every single sentence before showing them the next sentence and not allowing them to skim the page (for example the headings) and choose what to read.

Comment: I guess that's fair, but they can always move their finger and stop it, no? It seems the analog of presenting a lot of text taking over the screen.

Comment: yes, but that is like asking a sighted user to click before they can just scan the page - unnecessary